Possible degrees of the splitting field of a polynomial with repeated roots
I was hoping to get some clarification on a confusion I have regarding the degrees of a splitting field. Suppose $f$ is a polynomial of degree four over a field $\mathbb{k}$, with $L = \text{Split}_{\mathbb{C}/ \mathbb{k}}(f)$ the splitting field of this polynomial. I am told that the possible degrees of this splitting field are 4,8, and 12, the reason being that $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{k})$ embeds as a subgroup of $S_4$ since it must permute the roots of $f$. I was wondering if  $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{k}) \cong S_3$, as a subgroup of $S_4$, is also a possibility, so that the extension has degree 6. If $f$ has a repeated root, so that $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{k})$ permutes only the three distinct roots, could we then have an extension of degree 6?
Thanks in advance!

That claim about the possible degrees of the splitting field is incorrect. Every divisor of $24$ is a possible degree of the splitting field, and every subgroup of $S_4$ is a possible Galois group.

@QiaochuYuan got it; thank you so much for the clarification!

Repeated roots aren't the issue either; for example $f$ could be the product of a linear and irreducible cubic factor.

@QiaochuYuan Ah, right, so then only three roots need to be adjoined. Appreciate it! (:
